# DataProc Job Bigquery to MYSQL IS taking Long

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I have the following code which copy data from Bigquery to MYSQL here is my pyspark code

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('MySQL Data Loader').getOrCreate()



dataframe = spark.read.format("com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery") \
  .option("maxParallelism", 1000) \
  .load("<table>") \
  .cache()


print("Loading Done.....")  
 
dataframe.write.format('jdbc').option('url', f'jdbc:mysql://{MYSQL_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}/{MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME}') \
  .option('dbtable', MYSQL_TABLE_NAME).option('user', MYSQL_USER).option('password', MYSQL_PASSWORD) \
  .option("rewriteBatchedStatements", True) \
  .option('batchsize', BATCH_SIZE).mode('append').save()

# Stop the SparkSession
spark.stop()
```

Currently It copy around 100GB of data and taking more than 1 day to do so. How i can improve the loading time.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/) please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.